# changing font color mousedown/mouseup using nth-child selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I was wondering if I have the correct logic or syntax to my jQuery. So this simple jquery is what I think is logically correct. Let me tell you what I actually want to happen, so I have a menu navbar and I want it to change font color alternately as I scroll down or scroll up. So since I have this ul>li class for the slides I used it to determine if it's odd or even with the use of the nth-child syntax. So, I Decided to assign it in variables and then used the if else to filter to what color they are going to display.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var odd = $(".fullpage-data>ul>li:nth-child(odd)");
var even = $(".fullpage-data>ul>li:nth-child(even)");

if odd.mousedown(function() {
    $("#menu>ul>li").css("color","red");
})
else even.mousedown(function () {
    $("#menu>ul>li").css("color","white");
})

})
```

Also, Is it possible to have the mousedown and mouseup in the same if or else?

Comment: any reason to do this with js rather than css?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using CSS pseudo class hover instead of mousedown and mouseup. and ofcourse you can use nth-child selector as well.

ex:

```
.fullpage-data ul li:nth-child(odd):hover{color:red;}
.fullpage-data ul li:nth-child(even):hover{color:white;}
```

Comment: Hi! I have to use the mouseup and mousedown function because what I want to happen is as the user scrolls down or up the menu font color changes. Since my site have an alternate image - white background - image - white background order